# Does Language Learning SE have a Twitter account, and if yes, where can I find it?

Tags: support, site-promotion

Some (many?) Stack Exchange sites have Twitter accounts: Stack Overflow has [@StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow), Japanese StackOverflow has [@jaStackOverflow](https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow), English Language Learners has [@StackEnglishLL](https://twitter.com/StackEnglishLL), Chinese Stack Exchange has [@StackChinese](https://twitter.com/StackChinese), Russan SE has [@StackRussian](https://twitter.com/StackRussian), Chess SE has  [@StackChess](https://twitter.com/StackChess), etc.

Retweeting tweets from such accounts can help in **promoting** the site.

So, does Language Learning SE have a Twitter account? If yes, where is it? I have not been able to find it.

**Update**:

- Beta sites do not automatically get a Twitter account. See [Why is it so difficult to find the twitter account for a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548/340816) on Meta SE.
- Jeff Atwood's blogpost [Twitter Question Feeds for Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/) from January 2011 has a list of Twitter accounts that were available at that point in time.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have such an account, as you've figured out. However, there's technically nothing stopping us from setting one up as long as we have community support. Here's a [script for an automatic bot](https://github.com/wizzwizz4/retrostack-birdsong) that retweets popular hot questions on LL and provides a link to them. If we could configure to pull data from our site, we'd be set.

That being said, we'd have to consider what benefit the bot would actually have on our site participation. [ELU's Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackEnglish) only has about 700 followers, and keep in mind that ELU is one of the largest sites on the network in terms of site traffic and number of users. Because of this, we'd have to weigh the benefits of setting up such an account, but I'd agree that it's still worth a try.