# Additional site promotion ideas

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I have gone through a bunch of meta SE sites to see if they have any site promotion ideas that we hadn't though of yet. Here is what I found:

- A **leaflet or flyer**, see e.g. the [leaflet for English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/english-se-pamphlet-hang-up-or-hand-out-to-your-friends-and-classmates). (This idea was also suggested on [Russian Language SE](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/how-to-promote-our-site).
- A leaflet like this may be used to promote the site at exhibitions (e.g. Expolangues in France, as mentioned on [ELL](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/promoting-english-language-usage), or [Expolingua](http://www.expolingua.com/en/) in Berlin), in public libraries, adult education centres (e.g. Volkshochschulen in Germany), etc.
- A **subreddit**, as proposed on [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/sites-shutting-down-what-is-our-position).
- A "Language learning **flashmob week**", like the [stats flashmob week](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-promote-the-site) proposed on Cross Validated.
- "Polishing" the [**questions with the highest number of views**](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits), as proposed on [French Language SE](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/359/11052).
- A **question asking competition** or question challenge week, as proposed on [Chinese Language SE](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/how-about-chinese-new-year-%E6%98%A5%E8%8A%82-question-challenge-week) (although there was [no response when the idea was repeated two years later](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/anyone-up-for-a-question-asking-competition)). The idea came from a StackOverflow blog post from 2012: [Hot Topics: A Contest Formula that Works](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/hot-topics-a-contest-formula-that-works/).
- **Contacting language-learning communities** such as [Polyglot Club](http://polyglotclub.com/), as suggested on [Russian Language SE](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/how-to-promote-our-site).
- Writing a great **blogpost**, as suggested on [Chess SE](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/108/10867). (This requires publication on a blog with a significant amount of traffic.)
- Creating **our own blog**, like [Worldbuilding SE's blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory) on Medium, as suggested by @fi12 in our [meta question about YouTube videos](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/should-we-create-a-youtube-account-to-promote-our-site). [SE announced in December 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244467/340816) that it would no longer start community blogs for individual sites. But it turns out that @PythonMaster already created an [**unofficial LL SE blog**](http://languagelearningseblog.weebly.com/).
- Creating a **video**. See also [Making a promotional video for a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294553/340816) and [Featuring Stack Exchange on YouTube - Anything I Should be Aware of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284546/340816) on Meta SE.
- **Retweeting upvoted questions** on Twitter, as suggested on [Chess SE](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/108/10867). That is ... [if LL SE has a Twitter account](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/416/does-language-learning-se-have-a-twitter-account-and-if-yes-where-can-i-find-i). Literature SE, for example, has a [community-maintained Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/2191).
- Promoting the site on **LinkedIn**, as suggested on [Cognitive Science](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/q/130/13937) (although it seems that they never did this).
- Find closed questions on other sites that may be relevant here and **migrate** them, as suggested on [Open Date SE](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/14002). This raises the question how to find close questions on other sites. See [Where can I find all the closed questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174062/340816) on Meta Stack Exchange.
- A somewhat similar post on [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/105/23586).
- In addition on *how* to promote the site, someone on Cognitive Sciences SE asked, [**what is the best time of day to promote the site?**](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2141/13937).
- Publishing **guest posts on blogs about language learning** (since there are so many language learning blogs), as [proposed by Hatchet](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/615/should-we-widen-the-scope-of-our-site-and-if-yes-how#comment1032_615).

We can't do all of these things—let alone simultaneously—but we can do some of them, one after another.

**Update**: I put a slightly modified copy of the above text on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285269/340816), where it is more likely to be found by participants of other beta sites. (The changes concern references to LL SE itself.)

Comment: You've done a lot of great research here, great job!

Comment: I do like the subreddit idea a lot: [Language Learning Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/languagelearning/) has about 70000 users.

Comment: @PythonMaster What do you think of the blog idea, since you already created an unofficial LL SE blog?

Comment: I'm going to make a Reddit post on the LL subreddit as a sort of introduction to our site.

Comment: [Done!](https://www.reddit.com/r/languagelearning/comments/55wpty/language_learning_stack_exchange_is_a_great/)

Comment: I made a post in the LinkedIn group [Language Experts](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2347482/2347482-6194190013882716184).

Comment: The blog idea would be cool and much more better than the weird one that I created and kinda abandoned

Comment: Now completely abandoned since we have an official blog

Answer (score 3):

So far we have:

- An [unofficial Twitter account](https://twitter.com/Language_Blog) founded by me that really only reshares our blog posts from our Medium publiication. More on this will be posted in a future post here at Meta.
- The [blog](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog) we officially started in Medium